# PHP MYSQL Insert dynamic array into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

The dynamic HTML form (with some js help) and PHP script below insert user entered values into MySQL successfully, except that all rows from the form are placed in one row on the database. What am I doing wrong?

Dynamic form HTML:

```html
<table id="dataTable" class="form" border="4">
    <tbody  style="font-size:8pt">
    <th>
        <td align="center">Company</td>
        <td align="center">Project</td>
        <td align="center">Sub-Project</td>
        <td align="center">Change From</td>
        <td align="center">Change To</td>
        <td align="center">Activity</td>
        <td align="center">Responsible</td>
        <td align="center">Dur</td>
    </th>
    <tr  >
        <p>
        <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
        <td><input style="width:100px" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="coa[]" value="<?php echo $co; ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="Projectname[]" style="font-size:10pt">
                <option selected="selected" required="required">Select project</option>
                <?php
                    foreach($proj as $item){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $item; ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
                <?php
                    }                           
                    mysqli_close($conn);
                ?>
            </select>   
        </td>
        <td><input style="width:100px" type="text" required="required" name="Subproj[]"></td>
        <td><input style="width:130px" type="text" required="required" name="Changefrom[]"></td>
        <td><input style="width:130px" type="text" required="required" name="Changeto[]"></td>
        <td><input style="width:300px" type="text" required="required" name="Activity[]"></td>                      
        <td><input style="width:90px" type="text" required="required" name="Resp[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" required="required" class="small"  name="Durest[]"></td>
        </p>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

PHP script:

```php
<?php 
    include("../../db_conn_ci_i.php");
    if(isset($_POST)==true && empty($_POST)==false){
    $co=$_POST['co'];               
    $chkbox = $_POST['chk'];
    $Projectname=$_POST['Projectname'];
    $Subproj=$_POST['Subproj'];         
    $Changefrom=$_POST['Changefrom'];
    $Changeto=$_POST['Changeto'];   
    $Activity=$_POST['Activity'];   
    $Resp=$_POST['Resp'];
    $Durest=$_POST['Durest'];
    }
    $pco=implode(',',$co);
    $pa=implode(',',$Projectname);
    $pb=implode(',',$Subproj);
    $c=implode(',',$Changefrom);
    $d=implode(',',$Changeto);
    $e=implode(',',$Activity);
    $f=implode(',',$Resp);
    $g=implode(',',$Durest);

    $sql=" INSERT INTO projects (co,Projectname,Subproj,Changefrom,Changeto,Activity,Resp,Durest) 
    VALUES ('.$pco.','.$pa.','.$pb.','.$c.','.$d.','.$e.','.$f.','.$g.')    ";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

etc,etc
?>
```

Any advice?
Thank you.

Comment: You can remove the ">"'s from your query

Comment: 7 columns and 8 values?

Answer (score 2):

You have added an extra column but not added a value for it. Since you are inserting seven columns with eight values, that's why it's not working for you. Your insert query is like below.

```
$sql=" INSERT INTO projects (Projectname,Subproj,Changefrom,Changeto,Activity,Resp,Durest) 
    VALUES ('.$pa.','.$pb.','.$c.','.$d.','.$e.','.$f.','.$g.')  ";

        $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: Apologies. The field 'co' was there. My typo.

Comment: @nuddernuby You mean that you also need add $pco also in table ?

Comment: @nuddernuby ok then your query is like this
$sql=" INSERT INTO projects (co,Projectname,Subproj,Changefrom,Changeto,Activity,Resp,Durest) 
    VALUES ('.$pco.','.$pa.','.$pb.','.$c.','.$d.','.$e.','.$f.','.$g.')    ";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

i think you need to add dot (.) in this variable "$pco". please look at my query.

Comment: @ jalpa  It still loads the different rows in one row. Correctly allocated to the respective fields, but all rows in one 'cell'. BTW, it also stores the dot(.) in the table.

Comment: @nuddernuby try to replace this query

$sql="INSERT INTO projects (Projectname,Subproj,Changefrom,Changeto,Activity,Resp,Durest) 
    VALUES ('".$pa."','".$pb."','".$c."','".$d."','".$e."','".$f."','".$g."')  ";

Comment: I tried the '".$pa."' etc  option but I still get one row in the database, i.e. if there are 5 rows in the table, it places five values (comma separated) in each column.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @nuddernuby i have tried this query on my local machine and its working fine for me can you please try again please `$sql=" INSERT INTO projects (co,Projectname,Subproj,Changefrom,Changeto,Activity,Resp,Durest) VALUES ('".$pco."','".$pa."','".$pb."','".$c."','".$d."','".$e."','".$f."','".$g."')";` or can you please send me screenshot.

Comment: It won't let me post screenshot - reputation too low. I get ABC
New HQ
Apple


ABC,ABC | CD,EF | GUI,Apple

ABC,ABC,ABC | CD,EF,New HQ | GUI,XYZ,Apple

Comment: Sorry, it won't let me post screenshot - reputation too low. As per illustration below (for Columns co,Projectname,Subproj) I get:

1. With 2 rows input (your code): ABC,ABC | CD,EF | GUI,Apple
2. With 3 rows input (your code): ABC,ABC,ABC | CD,EF,New HQ | GUI,XYZ,Apple
3. With new script: ABC | New HQ | Apple  -- Please note that, for example 3 , I used the code "VALUES ('".array_values($co)[$i]."','".array_values($Projectname)[$i]."', etc etc.." after "for ($i=0;$i<count($Projectname); $i++) { " . This did split the arrays - but only posted the last row of the array. Not there yet!